# Showing NetBeans where a PHP class is defined

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans for my PHP programming. Most often it's pretty clever in finding class declarations, especially if they are found in the same project. But sometimes it just refuses to find a class' definition, like a PEAR library's class. Is there a way for me to show NetBeans where a certain class is defined, manually, and enjoy the joys of autocompletion?

I'm using NetBeans 6.7 Beta

Answer (score 1):

On my system I have added my PHP include path to Netbeans global include path.

Tools -> Options -> PHP Tab

Generally if a class is in the same project, the reference will be available as Netbeans scans the entire project.

I'm using Netbeans 6.5 so at this point I might suggest that its a bug in the beta.

Do you have an unusual folder structure, or odd class name?